# Add App Icon on lower left corner in lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, passbook

I have installed app on device and i want to show it in left lower corner in lock screen when it entered a specific region but i do not want to use iBeacon, Is there is a way to make using passbook card that i can add a locations and date/time to the pass.json file and read that location and time from the passbook card and show the app on the lower left corner on lock screen of the iPhone depend on the location or time from passbook card ?

Comment: Do mean that when you add a Pass to passbook from your App, you want your app to appear in the bottom left corner? It's worth understanding that Passbook doesn't communicate directly with your app. Once your app installs a pass, the handling of relevance is taken over by Passbook.

Comment: I don't think you can make an app icon appear on the lock screen based on tripping a location with passbook.   You can however, use in-app geofences to do this, so iBeacon isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Also, with iOS 9, the app that's displayed in the bottom left is also controlled by Siri, I believe, learning user patterns and showing contextually relevant apps.

Comment: @davidgyoung you say is there is a way to show my app in lower left corner using geofences ? how can i do that ? I can shows notifications up to the users like push notifications but how can i added to lock screen ?

Answer (score 0):

The launch icon you see on the lock screen is put there `CoreLocation` launches an app into the background based on iBeacon or Geofence detection.  While you said you don't want to use iBeacons with your app, you can still accomplish the same thing with CoreLocation Geofences.  The way it would work is that you would register the geofences with your app, and then **when you cross the geofence with your app in the background, the icon will appear on the lock screen.  Tapping on the icon launches your app.**

You can find a tutorial on setting up Geofences with your app here:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift

Comment: Perfect, how about killing the app not put it in background, is still work and show the app icon on lock screen.

Comment: And by the way i implement that tutorial and put the application in background and when entered the geofence it shows up a local notifications not the app on lock screen in lower left screen.

Comment: You probably want to comment out the local notification.  It might be that iOS does not show the icon on the lock screen if a notification is sent -- so it just sends one visual notification.